# Monitor file access with ACL enabled

Tags: monitoring, nagios, access-control-list, user-accounts

I would like to check that user 'robert' has read access to a file but is not enabled neither write it nor execute it.

Since acl are enabled, there is more than one way to do it.  I would like to check if user has access.

I would like not to have to know the password of 'robert' neither to log in as 'rober', because 'robert' may have extensive priviledges.

Indeed, the following command create a new session for robert, and as `root` can execute any command as any user.

```
# #NOT COOL enought!
# su robert -c '[[ -r my_file ]] && [[ ! -w my_file ]] && [[ ! -x my_file ]]'
```

Is there a way to avoid the user switching?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a plugin that can already do this. 30 seconds on google didn't yield anything either. There's a [category of plugins for similar purposes on Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/File-System), but nothing that matches exactly what you need.

You'll probably have to write it yourself. A simple bash script to look at the output of `getfacl /path/to/my_file` and/or `stat /path/to/my_file` would be sufficient, depending on ACL use.

Be sure to read the Nagios plugin developer guidelines first, if you do this.